# what does this mean ? php code

Tags: php, html

while i was printing this:
the code :

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['insert']))
{
           echo $_POST['string'];

}
echo '

<form action ='course.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='string' rows='6' colos='30' ></textarea>
<br />
<input type='submit' value='send' name='insert' />
</from>
'

?>
```

code i got this !

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\AppServ\www\course.php on line 6
```

could you tell me what does this mean ?

thank you a lot

Comment: Quotes quotes quotes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the misuse of quotes.

Comment: It means that you have a string where the parser doesn't expect to find a string.

Comment: Why the down vote? He's a new user and came across his first PHP error? This is why I am getting fed up with SO!

Comment: @PeterStuart exactly my point! turning away potential moderators :P

Comment: I'm scared to reply before I get flagged as being "too chatty". I hope the next mods help make SO a better community like it was a few years ago. Thanks user, for the good question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurred because you are using single quotations and then single quotations in between the single quotes, which is confusing the server as it expects ";" after the second single quote.

I recommend you change your code to this:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['insert']))
{
           echo $_POST['string'];

}
?>

<form action ="course.php" method="post">
<textarea name="string" rows="6" cols="30" ></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="send" name="insert" />
</from>
```

That way you separate all PHP and HTML code. If you wish to add more PHP code within the HTML form you can do so by adding something like this:

Here you are opening a PHP tag, calling a variable, then closing the tag and continuing with your HTML code.

There are other methods to fix your problem. You can read up about it here:http://www.yourwebskills.com/phpquotes.php

Answer (score 5):

You have not escaped the ' in what you are trying to print. Therefore php parses until the action = ' and then looks for a php entity that follows it, but does not understand what follows.

Replace all the ' in what you are trying to print with \' to escape them.

You also misspelled the closing form tag.

Answer (score 0):

remove `echo '`, replace `</from>` with ` and add a php closing tag

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['insert']))
{
           echo $_POST['string'];

}
?>

<form action ='course.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='string' rows='6' colos='30' ></textarea>
<br />
<input type='submit' value='send' name='insert' />
</form>
```